Correct way of setting an elements position in relevance to another element or pointer
What is the correct approach to set the position of a object in relevance to the pointer? I have tried
private void TextBlockPressed(object sender,   PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var currentPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(sender as UIElement);
  Canvas.SetLeft(element, e.Position.X);
}


Difficult to say with such few code. Canvas.SetLeft (and other SetXXX) only has a meaning and works if element is a child of a Canvas parent. Otherwise it depends on the parent.

It's hard to say which manner you mean, in proportion on an anchor or the fixed distance. In consideration of an element and its child content, see Alignment, margin, padding.

as an example: let's say you want to drag and move a rectangle on a canvas.

Let me show you a basic example which lets you drag a Rectangle on a Canvas:
*.xaml
<Canvas
    x:Name="CanvasControl"
    Background="Transparent"
    PointerMoved="CanvasControl_PointerMoved"
    PointerPressed="CanvasControl_PointerPressed"
    PointerReleased="CanvasControl_PointerReleased">
    <Rectangle
        Width="100"
        Height="100"
        Fill="SkyBlue"
        PointerPressed="Rectangle_PointerPressed" />
</Canvas>

*.xaml.cs
private UIElement? DraggingUIElement { get; set; }

private Point DeltagStartPoint { get; set; }

private void Rectangle_PointerPressed(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DraggingUIElement = sender as UIElement;
}

private void CanvasControl_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DraggingUIElement = null;
}

private void CanvasControl_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is not Canvas canvasControl)
    {
        return;
    }

    DeltagStartPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(canvasControl).Position;

}

private void CanvasControl_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (DraggingUIElement is null ||
        sender is not Canvas canvasControl)
    {
        return;
    }

    var point = e.GetCurrentPoint(canvasControl).Position;
    double deltaX = point.X - DeltagStartPoint.X;
    double deltaY = point.Y - DeltagStartPoint.Y;

    double elemnetX = Canvas.GetLeft(DraggingUIElement);
    double elementY = Canvas.GetTop(DraggingUIElement);

    double newX = elemnetX + deltaX;
    double newY = elementY + deltaY;

    Canvas.SetLeft(DraggingUIElement, newX);
    Canvas.SetTop(DraggingUIElement, newY);

    DeltagStartPoint = point;
}

UPDATE
If you want to center the rectangle on the pointer when the rectangle is clicked:
private void Rectangle_PointerPressed(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is not UIElement uiElement)
    {
        return;
    }

    DraggingUIElement = uiElement;
    var positionOnDraggingUIElement = e.GetCurrentPoint(DraggingUIElement).Position;
    double draggingElementCenterX = DraggingUIElement.ActualSize.X / 2;
    double draggingElementCenterY = DraggingUIElement.ActualSize.Y / 2;

    var delta = new Point(
        draggingElementCenterX - positionOnDraggingUIElement.X,
        draggingElementCenterY - positionOnDraggingUIElement.Y);
    Canvas.SetLeft(DraggingUIElement, Canvas.GetLeft(DraggingUIElement) - delta.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(DraggingUIElement, Canvas.GetTop(DraggingUIElement) - delta.Y);
}


This is actually the exact same approach I ended up using. Thank you for the answer. Now to ask you an additional question, what if you want the rectangle to be positioned so the pointer is in the center? In other words, when you are dragging the object around it is always centered on the pointer.

Updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Will test it out, thank you!
